# Can I add an animated gif file to JButton?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jbutton, animated-gif

I'm trying to add a .gif file into a JButton, but seems like it doesn't work - the gif file didn't move, it displayed like a normal Image.

Here are my codes:

+The ImageButton Class:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;

/**
 * Button which display a png or gif image.
 * */

public class ImageButton extends JButton {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private ImageIcon defaultIcon;
private ImageIcon hoverIcon;

/**
 * Create a normal JButton.
 * */

public ImageButton(){
    super();
}

/**
 * Create a new ImageButton Object.
 * @param img1 url of normal image of the button
 * @param img2 url hover image of the button
 * @param width button width
 * @param height button height
 * */

public ImageButton(String img1, String img2, int width, int height){
    super();
    BufferedImage defaultIcon = null;
    BufferedImage hoverIcon = null;
    try {
        defaultIcon = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(img1));
        hoverIcon = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(img2));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.defaultIcon = new ImageIcon(defaultIcon);
    this.hoverIcon = new ImageIcon(hoverIcon);
    setIcon(this.defaultIcon);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));
    setBorder(null);
    setOpaque(false);
    setContentAreaFilled(false);
    setBorderPainted(false);
}

/**
 * Hover the button.
 * */

public void hover(){
    setIcon(hoverIcon);
}

/**
 * Return the button to normal.
 * */

public void down(){
    setIcon(defaultIcon);
}
}
```

+The Test Class:
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TestGifButton {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ImageButton button = new ImageButton("level3.gif","level3.gif", 150, 150);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.add(button);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

I used a looping .gif file.

So how can I fix it ? thanks a lot :'(

Comment: It doesn't answer my problem - the gif file can easily display on a JLabel, but not in my JButton.

Comment: [read post about](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18271876/714968) by @MadProgrammer

Comment: don't subclass JButton, if yes then to override set(Xxx)Icon implemented in Api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JButton button = new JButton(new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Images/BBishopB.gif")));
```

OR
Full Example :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ImageSwapOnButton {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("http://1point1c.org/gif/thum/plnttm.gif");

        Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(url);
        ImageIcon spinIcon = new ImageIcon(image);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(spinIcon));

        // create a static version of this icon
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(150,150,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics g = bi.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image,0,0,null);
        g.dispose();
        ImageIcon staticIcon = new ImageIcon(bi);

        JButton button = new JButton(staticIcon);
        button.setRolloverIcon(spinIcon);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, button);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, you might try this for your animation...

```
File file = new File("img/ani.gif");
URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
Icon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
JButton aniButt = new JButton(icon);
```

maybe you must also set the mouseover and pressed icons as well..

but read the https://stackoverflow.com/a/18271876/714968 ... (as mKorbel metioned!)