# How do I use a gif file in a Java program?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, gif

I'm trying to add a .gif image to a JButton, but can't seem to get the image to load when i run the code. I've included a screenshot. Included is the frame that's created. I'd really appreciate any help that can be provided. Stack is telling me I can't enter images yet, so it created a link for it. I'm also going to enclose the actual code here:

```
package java21days;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ButtonsIcons extends JFrame {
    JButton load, save, subscribe, unsubscribe;
    
    public ButtonsIcons() {
        super("Icon Frame");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        
        //Icons
        ImageIcon loadIcon = new ImageIcon("load.gif");
        ImageIcon saveIcon = new ImageIcon("save.gif");
        ImageIcon subscribeIcon = new ImageIcon("subscribe.gif");
        ImageIcon unsubscribeIcon = new ImageIcon("unsubscribe.gif");
        
        //Buttons
        load = new JButton("Load", loadIcon);
        save = new JButton("Save", saveIcon);
        subscribe = new JButton("Subscribe", subscribeIcon);
        unsubscribe = new JButton("Unsubscribe", unsubscribeIcon);
        
        //Buttons To Panel
        panel.add(load);
        panel.add(save);
        panel.add(subscribe);
        panel.add(unsubscribe);
        
        //Panel To A Frame
        add(panel);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        
        
    } //end ButtonsIcon Constructor
    
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        ButtonsIcons ike = new ButtonsIcons();
        
    }
    
} //end ButtonsIcon Class
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyy30.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I add an animated gif file to JButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592719/can-i-add-an-animated-gif-file-to-jbutton)

Comment: Did you try using absolute file paths for your icons?

Comment: My god! Thank you to gthanop. Adding the direct file path worked. I can't believe how easy that was. Thanks again!

Comment: A better, long term solution, is to embed your images and other resources in your Jar file and then loading them via `Class#getResource`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is.
Label or Jbutton and what ever else supports HTML 3.5
JLabel a = new JLabel("");

add that to your container.
[image]
Haven't figured out how to enter code sorry

Comment: I appreciate the tip. I used gthanop's method he gave and it worked. However, I'm going to try everyone people suggest (including yours), that way I can continue learning. Thanks again for the help.